# trouble with multiple get routings

Tags: node.js, express

I use express.js 4.2.0 on node 5.2.0. 
At first I had in my app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/form');
app.get('/', routes);
```

and in form.js

```
var routes = require('express').Router();
routes.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('form',{title:'Login',userField:'Username',passField:'Password',photos: photos});
});
module.exports = routes;
```

And it was working fine, I got to `localhost:3000/` and I was getting the form.

Now I want to add some code, so when I visit `localhost:3000/YY/download` it automatically downloads an image acording to the YY, the id.

So now I have in the app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/form');
var download = require('./routes/form');

app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');
app.get('/', routes);
app.get('/:id/download', download(app.get('multimedia')));
```

and in the form.js

```
var routes = require('express').Router();

routes.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('form',{title:'Login',userField:'Username',passField:'Password',photos: photos});
});

var download = function(dir){
    return function(req,res,next){
        var path;
        if(req.params.id==='01')
        {path = dir+ '/01.jpg';}
        else
        {path = dir+'/02.jpg';}
        res.download(path);
    } 
}

module.exports = routes;
module.exports = download;
```

Visiting `localhost:3000/YY/download` works fine, but visitng `localhost:3000/` does not work. GET is pending and eventually the page never loads.

Please help me to fix this, because I am confused.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `.exports` object in `form.js` when you do two calls to:

```
module.exports = routes;
module.exports = download;
```

So you're never exporting the router and express is getting confusing instructions (route partially matched, but it's not getting the router back).

If you really wanted to keep those two objects exportable, just do 
    module.exports.routes = routes;
    module.exports.download = download;

and change any references to it accordingly (`<obj>.routes` etc.)

I also recommend moving the `download()` into your form.js route logic and not exposing it in `app.js` at all. :)